# Vim colorscheme + resize = weird borders

Tags: vim, color-theme

I am using Vim 8.1. Recently I started using colorschemes. With colorschemes (whether default schemes like desert or plugin schemes like gruvbox) all works great except when I resize my window. Say I have two windows side by side, and I open Vim on either of the windows and begin to resize either window. This will result in the window that has Vim (or had, since even after I close Vim, the same pattern happens) to lose colors around the border. If I disable Vim's colorschemes, this effect doesn't happen. I've tried many things and a lot of googling to no avail.

Good image:

[image: Good image]

Bad image:

[image: Bad image]
<sup>(Click images to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think this happens, because there is not enough room to show a complete line. So a border is added. See also this issue: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/349

Answer (score 1):

I spent 6 months without true color using vim. It finally got to me. I found this comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/993#issuecomment-255651605

I was using `xterm-256color` as my default term emulator and I had `termguicolor` set in my vimrc.

I tried changing to nvim and the problem still persisted. I tried playing with vim specific terminal settings (like `&t_8f` and `&t_8b`) but still nothing. I finally decided to change my default term emulator to `st-256color`, everything worked after that.

I still don't know what the root cause is, I would love for an explanation of what is going on.

**TL;DR**: One way to get rid of this nasty behavior is to change your terminal emulator.